# How is oxytocin produced?

Tags: endocrinology, translation

Is oxytocin (or other peptide hormones) produced from a gene through translation, or is it made some other way?

Comment: seems like a straightforward question...all proteins are translated from mRNA that is transcribed from DNA - that's the central dogma of molecular biology - is there a reason you think that it could be made another way?

Comment: Peptides like oxytocin (I think it is only 9 AAs long) seem small enough that maybe a cell would synthesize them using proteins rather than by a ribosome translating a gene for them.

Comment: Some peptides are synthesized via nonribosomal peptide synthetases, so the question seems legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oxytocin is produced by cleavage of the protein of the [oxytocin/neurophysin I prepropeptide](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/5020) gene. The precursor peptide is cleaved by [Proprotein-Convertase 1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/NP_000430.3)
. Mice lacking the [gene](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15779921) which encodes for this enzyme have reduced levels of oxytocin. The final step in the biosynthesis of oxytocin is carried out by [Peptidyl glycine alpha-amidating mono-oxygenase](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2769155).